# trying to fetch a textView from another screen in android

Tags: java, android

I have a home screen a data screen and a database. The user makes a selection on the home screen, the database then performs the actions to display this on the data screen by fetching the textViews on the data screen and updating them:

(do3 has been declared earlier in the constructor).

do3 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Do3);
do3.setText("SomeText");

So this happens in the database class....but it keep saying nullPOintException, I have broken the code down and it's because Do3 in the data screen hasn't been created and so null is getting assigned to do3 in the database screen.

In the home screen the activity is started in the following manor:

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DataScreen.class);
            //System.out.println(v.getTag().toString());
            myDb.findCountry("United_Kingdom");
            startActivity(nextScreen);
```

So my question is from the database screen can I get the Ids of the textViews on the data screen?

Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Kind regards Jamie

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the view before you access the textview. If you want to access the textview id without setContentView() method then you need to inflate the layout to the view.

Comment: Hi Huteri, temp is a View object but this was just created in the database class, I need to get the view object of the DataScreen class into the database class.